# Bulk delete > 50,000 rows from a list in SharePoint Online

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I need to refresh a SharePoint Online list every day i.e. (1) delete all old data, (2) feed in new data
I have created 2 flows in Power Automate (PA) to do tasks (1) , (2)
The PA flow for create items (2) runs quite fast and uploads data in 1h
However, the PA flow for delete items (1) is very slow and cleans data in 13h+
I have experimented with different types of optimizations like batch requests using HTTP connector, but I suspect that SharePoint settings don't allow fast delete of list items

My organization policy prevents me from deleting SharePoint list outright, without deleting the data within it. So delete existing list and create new list is not an option.

Is there any way to fast delete items in SharePoint Online list programmatically?
Does SharePoint itself have any feature to bulk delete items from list?

End users are not very familiar with Power Shell etc so trying to avoid it, however, if that's the only option, I am open to consider it.

Comment: [Power Automate Flow to batch delete SharePoint List Items](https://www.tachytelic.net/2021/06/power-automate-delete-sharepoint-items/)

Comment: How much churn is there in the data? Can you identify which items have changed (e.g. compare "last modified" timestamps on the source data and sharepoint items) and just refresh those rather than delete and reload the entire list?